# How to use CoreNFC in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, nfc, multiplatform

I'm totally new in xamarin.

I'm trying to use CoreNFC in my xamarin.forms multiplatform app.

But I don't know how to do it because i can only import CoreNfc in myapp.ios and not in myapp.

There is someone that know how to do it ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core NFC belongs to the iOS Framework, so you can import and use it only in our iOS Project.

You could implement the NFC feature on each platform you want to support and use a interface and the Xamarin Dependency Service, to have access to these platform specific implementations in your shared code.

Or you look around for a plugin which did this work for you. A starting point could be NFCForms from poz1. But if I remember well it has so far only support for Android and Windows Phone.